# Return column names in KSQL in KTable

Tags: ksqldb

I am using Kafka KSQL REST API to make a query (`/query`) and inside the response I can access resulting columns with this API: https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/api.html#run-a-query-and-stream-back-the-output

`row.columns[i] (?) – The value contained in a single column for the row. The value type depends on the type of the column.`

So I can get access to column values, not column names.

Is there any way I could access column names too or I should manually parse the request KSQL to pull the column names from there?

For example, instead of 
`[1524760769983,"1",1524760769747,"alice","home"]`
I would like to get `{"columnA":1524760769983,"columnB":"1","columnC":1524760769747,"columnD":"alice","columnE":"home"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible currently. I've logged [#2364](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/2364) as an enhancement request as I can see that it would be valuable.

Comment: great, if that would be possible, that would be really nice.